# How to do a MySQL query with these relational tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have the following tables

```
videos

id | title | url


video_to_category

video_id | category_id
```

I would like a query to get once all videos from the video table that have a certain category_id

Comment: What is the mapping? Does "video_id = id"? We need a lot more information!

Comment: Yes, it is :) thank you all for your answers, I picked the easiest one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM videos v, video_to_category vc
WHERE v.id=vc.video_id AND category_id=YOURID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join

```
select a.* 
from videos as a 
inner join video_to_category as b on a.id = b.video_id
and b.category_id = 'Your_value';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` AS `v`,`video_to_category` AS `vtc`
WHERE `v`.`id`=`vtc`.`video_id`
AND `vtc`.`category_id`='YOUR CHOICE'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` `v` INNER JOIN `video_to_category` `vtc` 
ON `v`.`id`=`vtc`.`video_id`
AND `vtc`.`category_id`='YOUR CHOICE'
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bec8d3/1)

Comment: Hi, could you tell me what the difference, using join and not?

Comment: Please check the example in my edited answer. The result is the same in both queries. @user3808307

Comment: Thank you Peter, I will take a look. Everybody is always so helpful here all the time

Answer (score 1):

```
select videos.* from videos 
inner join video_to_category 
on video_to_category.video_id = videos.id 
and video_to_category.category_id = 10
```

By analyzing your tables it seems what your column video_to_category have only 2 columns, if this is the case then you do not need to save it in different column, you can add a new column in videos table name 'category_id', but if you have some other columns hidden in this question then leave it.

Comment: The thing is some videos have many categories, so they will be more than once in that table.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select vi.id, vi.title, vi.url from videos vi left join video_to_category 
 vc on (vi.id = vc.video_id) where vc.category_id = '$category_id'
```

$category_id is the variable where you put your given variable id. I use "$" cause i use php varaiable here.

Thanks